# Python moviepy reader not defined when writing video file

Tags: python, python-3.x, moviepy

I am trying to combine a few sets of AudioFileClip's and ImageClip's into one movie. But am having a weird error, I have spent a long time and tried many things to attempt and get it to work.

I have tried:

- Creating one combined AudioClip and then adding it to the combined ImageClips instead of adding a bunch of ImageClips that already have audio attached
- Different ways of putting the clips together such as .set_audio and using a temp audio file when writing the clip to a file
- Testing a similar situation in the console which worked
- Searching and searching through moviepy docs and previous questions

```
from moviepy import editor as mp
from gtts import gTTS
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3


class test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.clips = []

    def add_clip(self, text, picture_path, audio_path):
        tts = gTTS(text)
        tts.save(audio_path)

        duration = MP3(audio_path).info.length

        image_clip = mp.ImageClip(picture_path, duration=duration)
        audio = mp.AudioFileClip(audio_path)
        image_clip = image_clip.set_audio(audio)
        self.clips.append(image_clip)
        audio.close()
        image_clip.close()


t = test()
t.add_clip("Hello", 'screenshots/t3_bgykzb/main.png', 'screenshots/t3_bgykzb/main.mp3')
t.add_clip("Hello", 'screenshots/t3_bgykzb/main2.png', 'screenshots/t3_bgykzb/main.mp3')
t.add_clip("Hello", 'screenshots/t3_bgykzb/main3.png', 'screenshots/t3_bgykzb/main.mp3')

main_clip = mp.concatenate_videoclips(t.clips)
main_clip.write_videofile(f'screenshots/movie.mp4', fps=24)
main_clip.close()
```

I expect this to output an mp4 file that has 3 clips, each one saying hello using tts. The TTS works fine and outputs an mp3 correctly, it works fine when I comment out the set_audio line, but when I combine all of the clips into a single mp4 it has an error.

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_frame'
```

Full Error:
https://mystb.in/ulusafajan.rb

None of the objects in the list are None and I am confused why the concatenated clip doesnt have a reader

Any and all help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: The issue was that the audioclip cant be closed before writing to a file